# Не получается подключить шаблон к DRF

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-rest-framework

Всем привет пытался подключить шаблонизатор к DRF проекту, а конкретно к данной апишке:

```
class UserRegistrationView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'registration.html'

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = DefaultUser.objects.create(
                username=request.data['username'],
                email=request.data['email'],
            )

            user.set_password(request.data['password'])
            user.save()
            return Response({'message': 'User registered successfully.'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

но при попытке зайти на страницу user/register/ выходит полностью белый экран и в правом верхнем углу ошибка 405 Method Not Allowed. Ниже так же привел сам html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>User Registration</h1>
    <form id="registration-form" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br>

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br>

        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>

    <div id="message"></div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("registration-form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
            const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

            fetch('/user/register/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ username, email, password }),
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.message) {
                    document.getElementById("message").textContent = data.message;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```